# How to make Exception much simpler CodeIgniter4

Tags: codeigniter, exception, codeigniter-4

so, I have JWT authentication API using CI4, and one of the method is filtering which is telling if you has the token for JWT or not, if the user don't have the token it will return to an exception telling that JWT authentication is failed like this :

**Postman :**
[image: Postman Exception]

**Web :**
[image: Web Exception]

is it possible to make it more simpler like this ?, just a response and without a trace exception like in the first image
[image]

Here is the
**jwt_helper.php :**

```
<?php

use App\Models\AuthModel;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

function getJWT($headerAuth)
{
    if (is_null($headerAuth)) {
        throw new Exception("JWT Authentication failed");
    }
    return explode(" ", $headerAuth)[1];
}

function validateJWT($encodedToken)
{
    $key = getenv('JWT_SECRET_KEY');
    $decodedToken = JWT::decode($encodedToken, $key, ['HS256']);
    $authModel = new AuthModel();
    // * xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
    $authModel->getEmail($decodedToken->email);
}
function createJWT($email)
{
    $requestTime = time();
    $tokenTime = getenv('JWT_TOKEN_TIME');
    $tokenExpireTime = $requestTime + $tokenTime;
    $payload = [
        'email' => $email,
        'iat' => $requestTime,
        'exp' => $tokenExpireTime
    ];
    $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, getenv('JWT_SECRET_KEY'), 'HS256');
    return $jwt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This full stack is displayed only in DEVELOPMENT.

Edit your .ENV file accordingly.

```
CI_ENVIRONMENT = production
```

**UPDATE : More details**

So, of course, you have to write the error in a log file. This is probably already the case: you can check the CI log in the /writable/logs directory and the PHP log which is in your PHP directory (you can look for the error_log variable in your phpinfo).

Then you should try to display a simple and understandable error to your users, typically by redirecting them to /views/errors/html/production.php but giving them a bit more detail if you want, and/or specifying a HTTP_STATUS or an EXIT CODE (CI 4.3+).

The DEVELOPMENT mode (specified in the .env) is however not recommended because you will give too many details to the user and this can be harmful (display of connections, directories, etc.).

I recommend you to read this page :
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html#

Comment: If I changed it to Production then the Exception message wont show up and yes its much simpler and not showing exception error. Is it possible to show the exception message ?

Comment: or is it how it supposed to be what end user view when there is exception ?

Comment: I have added more details in the answer